# PHP page redirect adding target page to bottom of current page

Tags: php

I've got a registration page and a landing page, when the register button is pressed it activates a JS function in an external JS file (reg.js) that then runs reg.php, like so:

```
reg.html->reg.js->reg.php
```

If the registration succeeds it is supposed to redirect to a landing page (landing.php) but instead it is just appending the landing page to the bottom of the current page(reg.html), like so:

---

```
Register
[register button]


Landing
[landing page text]
```

---

The redirection code is:

```
 header('Location: landing.php');
```

Comment: `header()` sends browser codes (including redirects when used with Location), if you are calling PHP with Javascript in the background then you'll need to use Javascript to do the redirect

Comment: use `window.location = 'http://url';` in javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the sounds of it, you're posting via AJAX to a php script to process. PHP would then need to send some sort of success response back to the AJAX—something like:

```
if (registered) {
  header(201); // http response code for "created"
}
```

The AJAX callback would see that success, and then you would redirect the user client-side:

```
$.post().success(function() { window.location = '/landing.php'; });
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using javascript ajax ? If yes then you need to use

```
window.location = 'http://webiste.com';
```

If your javascript submits the form then you need to use header in PHP code like this:

```
header( 'Location: http://website.com/landing.php' ) ;
```

Don't forget to add http:// in the redirect url as this may be causing an issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if(registered)
{
  header( 'Location: /landing.php' ) ;
}

?>
```

or try to input the whole url.